# How to export to .obj with separate map-channels?

Tags: uv, export, obj

I'd like to export a .blend file with a UV-mapped texture, a displacement map and a normals map in 3 separate channels to an .obj file. Tried it with 3 UV Maps in 'Object data' but only 1 map will be exported. 3 separate objects with 3 separate maps or separate layers aren't working either. Do i need nodes...!?

Comment: GuruGanesh, when I saw your name, I thought of a comic I made about [Ganesh's mount](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENTU44Z0NJZ2dLaGc/edit?usp=sharing)...see if you like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .obj file format only supports a single UV map per object. There is no way to export an .obj file from blender with multiple UV maps. What you should do is use another file format such as FBX which does support multiple UV maps per object.